# return default ToString() for a class instance c#

Tags: c#

I have a class named Person

```
public class Person
    { 
      string name;
      int age;
      SampleObject(string name, int age)
      {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      }
      public override string ToString() 
      {
         string s = age.ToString();
         return "Person: " + name + " " + s;
      }
    }
```

I have overridden the ToString() to return the name of the person.

I am using the class in another class:

```
public class MyClass
{

public int Id {get;set;}

public Person person {get;set;}

}
```

Now, I want to access the class as

```
MyClass my = new MyClass();
```

I want that when I execute `my.person`, it should return the ToString() value of the person class without explicitly calling the `my.person.ToString()`

Is it possible and if possible, how can I make this happen.

Thanks

Comment: How would one access the Person representation of my.person then? If that isn't supposed to happen, perhaps the person instance should be a private field and the person property should be a string that just returns ToString() of the field, or something.

Comment: Why do you need this ?

Comment: @faridbekran  I just want to give a default return type for ease of development by the consumer of the developed class library. Useful for few cases.

Comment: @user1731788 Maybe this helps to develop easily but may cause some ambiguity in your code. That makes the code difficult to debug. specially in future

Comment: @faridbekran will be careful while implementing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your question very well. but one of solutions to your question is to use [implicit cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx).

```
    public class Person
    {
        string name;
        int age;
        public Person(string name, int age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string s = age.ToString();
            return "Person: " + name + " " + s;
        }
        // here
        public static implicit operator string(Person d)
        {
            return d.ToString();
        }
    }
    public class MyClass
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Person Person { get; set; }

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myclass = new MyClass();
        myclass.Person = new Person("test", 12);
        // use like this
        string name = myclass.Person;
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: @user1731788 Note that anyone other than yourself, or even future you might have a hard time understanding why a `Person` returns a `string` instead of an actual person instance. IMO, going down that path is a bad idea.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: agree with that

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thanks. I just want to give a default return type for ease of development by the consumer of the developed class library. Useful for few cases.

Comment: @faridbekran Thanks. Is it also possible to assign a string as an implicit method that can assign the value to the "name" property by default.
like my.person = "abc";
It internally set the "name" property of the "person" object.

Answer (score 3):

You can create another readonly property

```
public string PersonName { get {return this.person.ToString();} }
```

Or add checking for possible null

```
public string PersonName 
{
    get 
    {
        return (this.person == null) ? String.Empty : this.person.ToString();
    }
}
```

Based on your comment about setting `Name` of person by same property
I think approach with separated/specific property will be more maintainable

```
public string PersonName 
{
    get 
    {
        return (this.person == null) ? String.Empty : this.person.ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        if(this.person == null)
        {
            this.person = new Person(value, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            this.person.Name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A mashup of VB and C# syntax, perhaps?  ;-)

Comment: The readonly keyword is not necessary in a property (and is in fact forbidden) - the fact that only a getter is present is what defines the property as readonly.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, good to know. I have `vb.net` background :). maybe with `readonly` keyword readability can be little bid better. In `vb.net` keyword is required

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with operator overload.

```
public static implicit operator string(Person p)
{
    return p.ToString();
}
```

If you wish you can implement operator overload in MyClass to so it calls person as well.

```
public static implicit operator string(MyClass my)
{
    return my.person;
}
```

With this you can do something like

```
string personString = my;
// or my.person if you only implement it for Person
```

Also you don't need to have a string variable for the age.
Doing the following will work just fine.

```
return "Person: " + name + " " + age;
```

I would suggest to use string.Format though.

```
return string.Format("Person: {0} {1}", name, age);
```